# Reworking an existing macro into a for loop

Tags: excel, loops, for-loop, vba

I have an Excel macro to analyze data pulled from a webpage. I study water quality and run a monitoring network. At these sites I have automated water samplers that fire off during storms.

I use this macro to pull descriptive data from our website. It was originally set up in a static manner creating a new sheet for each site (there are 9 sites in total) and the code is long and repetitive. I want to rewrite it using a for loop to have a relatively small amount of code that executes for each site and returns the same information in the same format that I already have setup.

There are several parts to the original script that are essentially hard-coded for each site in that they have the site name and number.

- I want to make the site numbers and names swap in a new one each time the for loop goes through.

I have a web URL in the code, which is the same for each site except for the site number at the end.

- How can I keep that as a URL but substitute the site number during each for loop iteration?
- How do I define my list of site numbers and names?

The old macro starts by making a sheet("sheet1").select ... and then runs through the rest of the code. The next site is hard coded as sheet("sheet2").select , etc.

- I assume I will need to redo this so each iteration of the loop creates the next numbered sheet in sequence.

Below is a sample of the code I am working with:

```
Workbooks.Add

Worksheets.Add().Name = "Rivers Ridge Summary"

Worksheets.Add().Name = "Sheppard Data"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "Sheppard Summary"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "Lucas Creek Data"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "Lucas Creek Summary"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "Ramsgate Data"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "Ramsgate Summary"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "Professional Place Data"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "Professional Place Summary"


Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Rivers Ridge Data"
Sheets("Rivers Ridge Data").Select
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://waterdata.usgs.gov/va/nwis/uv?cb_72199=on&cb_63680=on&cb_99234=on&format=rdb&period=1&site_no=0204279245" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = _
    "uv?cb_72199=on&cb_63680=on&cb_99234=on&format=rdb&period=1&site_no=0204279245"
```

...etc. etc.. all the rest of the code here.. and then the next site

```
Sheets("Sheppard Data").Select

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://waterdata.usgs.gov/va/nwis/uv?cb_72199=on&cb_63680=on&cb_99234=on&format=rdb&period=1&site_no=0204289989" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = _
    "uv?cb_72199=on&cb_63680=on&cb_99234=on&format=rdb&period=1&site_no=0204289989"
```

..followed by all of the code...
and so on for each site..

"rivers Ridge Data" is one site (Sheppard is another), and "0204279245" is the site number. I want these to swap out during each iteration of the loop.

Please follow up if you need more information or a sample of what I am working on.

Comment: can you please split it in several paragraph instead of one?

Comment: You need to show some code, that you need help with.

Comment: You could run a `For Each Loop` like this: `For Each xSht In Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2",...))` then you can use `xSht` as the replace for the `sheets("sheet***")` like `Sheets("Sheet***").Select` becomes `xSht.Select` ;)

Comment: I have added some code above as requested Davesexcel

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a setup tab with 2 columns, the site name and site number. Then you can loop through that list. In the loop, you can create data and summary sheets, then concatenate the number into the web address. It might look something like this.

```
Sub CollectAndReport()
Dim sWeb as string, sWeb2 as string
Dim i as integer
Dim sName as String

sWeb="www.google.com"

For i =2 to 10
sName = Sheets("Setup").Range("A"&i).Value
Worksheets.add sName
sWeb2 = sWeb & Sheets("Setup").("B"& i).Value
```

...your other code here

`Next i
   End Sub`